# Php Mysql Display sum of 2 columns in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to display the result of "Vendido -Pagado" (2 columns of my table) in html but the following code doesn't work, any clue why?

```
 <?php
    //connect to db
    include '../connect.php';

    $saldo = "SELECT Vendido-Pagado AS Saldo FROM Cooks WHERE Mail = '$email'";
    $resultsaldo = mysqli_query($conn, $saldo);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($resultsaldo) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsaldo) {
                  echo  '<a class="w-nav-link navlink right" href="../misaldo.php">Saldo: '
  .$row3['Saldo']. "</a>";

                  }}          else { echo "There was an error fetching the total";}

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: *"Php Mysql Display sum of 2 columns in html"* - so where does "sum" come into play? Use the `sum()` aggregate function or add `+`.

Comment: you also have a major syntax error. I think you're doing math in the wrong place ;-)

Comment: *"Hi the sum is already in the sql statement –  user3683347 3 mins ago"* - Oh, where's this? and where's `$email` coming from?

Comment: in the sql, "Vendido-Pagado" is the difference between column "Vendido" minus column "Pagado" (both are floats). $email comes from here : $email= "".$_SESSION['user_email']."";

Comment: that isn't how it's done. ^ you can't expect that to work with a minus like that, not that way anyway. Checking for errors would have told you that you have an SQL error near `Vendido-`

Comment: how would you do it? it works when i do it directly on the server

Comment: plus, seeing you're using sessions, has the session been started?

Comment: `select sum(Vendido - Pagado)` that ought to work for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii-just tried what you suggested as well as normans way but still not working. When i take out the code the page works fine though. And yes the session is started

Comment: you should post your db schema and tell us what the expected results are to be. Also, I take it you want to substract, correct? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Vendido = 123 or 123.45 ? Pagado = 123 or 123.45 ? Vendido is what, varchar, int? Pagado is what, varchar, int? I asked you a 1/2 hour ago to post your db schema, you didn't do that. How do you expect us to help you find a solution? It's quite simple, but we can't guess and post answers to what we don't know about. I can't help you anymore, so I wish you well on this, good luck; I am moving on now and closing this tab.

Comment: Hi Fred, i solved it by myself as your help was apparently not available. Turns out it was just a parenthesis missing after the while statement

Comment: *well well well,* will you look at that. Error reporting would've told you that.

Answer (score 2):

For SUM in MYSQL Query, you can use [**MYSQL SUM aggregate function**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
$saldo = "SELECT (SUM(Vendido) + SUM(Pagado)) AS Saldo FROM Cooks WHERE Mail = '$email'";
```

OR

I have used `$row3['col1']` and `$row3['col2']` for showing how to sum up the two columns do not forget to change column's name

`col1` , `col2`.

```
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsaldo) {

echo "Sum of two columns : ".($row3['col1'] + $row3['col2']);

}
```

Note: also if you are using `mysqli` is better to use [**mysqli prepared statements.**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: @user3683347 doing `SELECT Vendido-Pagado` doesn't constitute as doing "Vendido minus Pagado", it's an outright MySQL syntax error.

Comment: @Norman, just tried the second option like this:
<?php
        
        
        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultsaldo) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
       
     while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsaldo) {

echo  '<a class="w-nav-link navlink right" href="../misaldo.php">Saldo:'   .($row3['Vendido'] - $row3['Pagado']).   "</a>";

}}
     mysqli_close($conn);

?>

Comment: @Noman - I think the OP wants to substract rather than add. `select sum(Vendido - Pagado)` type of thing. I could be wrong though, but given their query `SELECT Vendido-Pagado`, it looks like it.

Comment: yeah @Fred-ii- he wants to substract the columns.  can you please let us know.

Comment: @user3683347 you were asked to post your db schema. We don't know what your column types are. varchar? int? other? MySQL can't do math on anything other than a column type that can handle integers.

Comment: @user3683347 please let us know what you want actually. #Fred i know i have to change my query but he should confirm first. :) hope you understand

Comment: Yes I do @Noman - There's nothing else I can do to be of any further help in their question.

Comment: Thanks anyway dude :) @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use sql query.

Change this

```
SELECT Vendido-Pagado AS Saldo FROM Cooks WHERE Mail = '$email'
```

to

```
SELECT CONCAT( Vendido,  '-', Pagado ) AS Saldo FROM Cooks WHERE Mail = '$email'
```

Comment: it works and returns a table with column "Saldo" and row value 90 which is correct